# Is it possible that a variable declared after the main has file scope?

Tags: c, scope, control-structure

After running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x;
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
int x=5;
```

I expected the output should be `0`. Because of the **sequence control structure** of the program `int x;` should be executed first and then `0` is printed and finally `int x=5;` should be executed.  But it is giving the output `5`.

How is the program accesses `5` for the `x` in `printf`?

Comment: While I got this `error C2086: 'int x' : redefinition`. Need to change first `int x` to `extern int x` to work it through.

Comment: But compiles on GCC 4.8.1 with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g3 -std=c99`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first acts as a forward declaration, and the later acts as the actual definition.

Comment: Isn't the statements get executed sequentially and it should print `0` (as global variables are set to `0`)? Edited the question.

Comment: @haccks All initialization of global or static variables gets done well before `main` is called. In fact, in a case like yours the compiler may even set the value already during compilation, so it's already set when the executable is loading into memory.

Comment: @haccks By the way, this is what the "data" segment in object and executable files are for, to store initialized data like your variable. Uninitialized data (like you would have if you didn't initialize the variable `x` in your case) would end up in the "bss" segment, which is zeroed before `main` is called.

Comment: That mean after compilation, `5` get set to `x` already, right?

Comment: @haccks Yes that's correct. It's set already in the executable file and the value is loaded when the program is loaded. Also, declarations and definitions are not really statements that have to executed in any special order. In fact, complex initializations can take place in any order the compiler wants it to (it's implementation dependent).

Comment: Thanks. Got it. (I guessed that before but not sure about that :) ).

Answer (score 3):

Variable default values declared outside of functions get set before main ever runs. So what you are seeing is the correct behavior. Same goes for variables declared in other source files.

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are initialised before `main()` runs. That means that it's entirely possible for a function to access something which appears after it in the file, as long as it's visible (i.e. forward declared).

With that said, you shouldn't really have multiple declarations for the same variable in one file. It could lead to confusion (mainly for the programmer) about what and where it's actually initialised.

EDIT: To clarify, functions/variables in global scope are not executed like a sequence of statements inside a function. The location of the function's declaration/definition has absolutely no bearing on when it gets called in relation to any other code. It only determines what parts of the surrounding scope are visible to it. In your case, this means `main()` does not get called in between your two `int` lines. It gets called by the runtime when it's finished all other initialisation.

Comment: @haccks: I've edited my answer to address the question a little better.

Comment: That's nice. But wonder that `main` does not called between the two `int` lines!