# Why re-declaration of global variables is valid but not local of local variables?

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables, redefinition, redeclaration

If I declare `i` to be a global variable twice, then it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i;int i;
int main(void) 
{
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

But not if I declare it locally (twice)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int i;int i;
printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
error: redeclaration of ‘i’ with no linkage
```

Also, if in the 1st case I initialize i to some value `i=1`, then also it gives error `error: redefinition of ‘i’`

Why is does it exhibit such a behaviour ?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a tentative definition.

Comment: @devnull: How does it impact what is being compiled? Why are these variables treated differently?

Comment: @brokenfoot This is mostly a linker issue - files are compiled separately. Because it's the linker's job to "glue" the files together, tentative definitions make sense - but including an initializer "promotes" it to a definition (not a tentative definition). After all, it wouldn't make sense to have 2 different initializers for the same entity (and would be a maintenance nightmare). That's why it won't compile when you declare it with an initializer.

Comment: Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/q/21187163/2549281 is also on the same opic